# Ctrl + k + d not removing blank lines in HTML editor VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When auto formatting (ctrl + k + d) html editor in VS2012 it is not removing blank lines. This used to work in VS2010. I looked in the Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Formatting, but I didn't find anything to fix the issue. This was a handy feature when there was alot of html code. Does anyone know how to get this working in VS2012?

Below is a crude example. Ya, I know you can do this manually but auto formatting makes it easy.

```
            <article>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1
blank line
                </li>
                <li>Item 2
blank line
                </li>
blank line                   
blank line
            </ul>
blank line
blank line
blank line
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
blank line
blank line
blank line
                <li>Item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </article>
```

Comment: What would be "blank lines"? every blank line in the code? or only blank line in the end of document? I'm not aware that this functionality is built-in, maybe from an extension...

Comment: White space between tags, vertically.

Comment: I just tried this in VS 2010 Ultimate and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turns out that they removed this feature due to complaints. I had VS2010 Professional SP1 and it used to work. Here is a link from MSDN forums with explanation. [MSDN Format Document](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/188df4b2-7138-4070-8fcc-271abe645293/format-document-vs-2012-html?forum=vsx)